# Display an image from local network in HTML <img>

Tags: html, image

I'd like to use an `<img />` tag in HTML to display an image that sits on our local network (file system).

We have, well let's just say a lot, of images stored on our network, so they're not being served up by a web server.

The following work in IE, but not in Chrome or Firefox...

```
<img src="\\10.10.10.10\share1\files\images\robin.jpg" />
<img src="file://10.10.10.10/share1/files/images/robin.jpg" />
```

I understand it may be a security issue, but I'm working on a local web app and local network so I need to be able to get around this, specifically for Chrome.

Comment: Why wouldn't they be served up by a web server?

Comment: The images are stored all over the place on our network, it's a mess really but it's what I've got to work with...

Answer (score -1):

Run below command to solve ‘failed to load Network image’ in flutter web
so, use below command to run/build

run for debugging

```
flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html
```

production release

```
flutter build web --web-renderer html --release
```

I got this from https://protocoderspoint.com/failed-to-load-network-image-flutter-web/

Also Please read this documentation by Flutter for further understanding
https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/web-images
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/HtmlElementView-class.html